# etcdserver: request timed out

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I've backed up my etcd and after restoring it, i can't Create/Update/Delete anything in my cluster!

I've exactly went through the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/)

Here are my steps:

---

#### Backing up etcd

- Save the snapshop

  ```bash
  sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot save /tmp/etcd-backup-new.db \
    --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
    --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt \
    --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
  ```
- Check the status

  ```bash
  $ sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot status /tmp/etcd-backup-new.db --write-out=table

    +----------+----------+------------+------------+
    |   HASH   | REVISION | TOTAL KEYS | TOTAL SIZE |
    +----------+----------+------------+------------+
    | d8d0da24 |  7220348 |        874 |     1.9 MB |
    +----------+----------+------------+------------+
  ```

---

#### Restoring etcd

- Create Restore Point from backup

  ```bash
  sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot restore /tmp/etcd-backup-new.db \
  --data-dir /var/lib/etcd-backup
  ```
- Tell etcd to use new location

  ```bash
  sudo vim /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml
  ```

  ```yaml
    - hostPath:
        path: /var/lib/etcd-backup # Changed this ONLY!
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
      name: etcd-data
  ```

As far as i know, Kubelet restarts static Pods automatically. So, after a while everything seems good!

```bash
$ k get all -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-6d4b75cb6d-6cmtm         1/1     Running   1 (7d23h ago)   72d
kube-system   pod/coredns-6d4b75cb6d-wchss         1/1     Running   1 (7d23h ago)   72d
kube-system   pod/etcd-master                      1/1     Running   2 (7d23h ago)   72d
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-master            1/1     Running   1 (7d23h ago)   39d
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-master   1/1     Running   4 (7d23h ago)   72d
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-mqzbd                 1/1     Running   1 (7d23h ago)   72d
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-master            1/1     Running   4 (7d23h ago)   72d
kube-system   pod/weave-net-4xtwz                  2/2     Running   3 (7d23h ago)   49d

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  72d
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   72d

NAMESPACE     NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   72d
kube-system   daemonset.apps/weave-net    1         1         1       1            1           <none>                   49d

NAMESPACE     NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns   2/2     2            2           72d

NAMESPACE     NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-6d4b75cb6d   2         2         2       72d
```

---

#### The Probelem

So, it seems everything is fine but its not! e.g.

```bash
$ k run test --image nginx
  Error from server: etcdserver: request timed out
```

or

```bash
$ k rollout restart daemonset.apps/kube-proxy -n kube-system
  error: failed to patch: etcdserver: request timed out
```

What is my mistake?

P.S: Kubernetes version: `v1.24.1`